# Row-normalize a sparse matrix into zero mean in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, normalize, bsxfun

I have a large m *n sparse matrix Y. I would like to normalize each row of Y, so that each row has zero mean.

I first tried this. But the mean of each row is also subtracted from the zero entries, which is not what I want.

```
Ynorm = bsxfun(@minus, Y, Ymean);
```

Then I tried this.

```
[m, n] = size(Y);
nonZeroNum = nnz(Y); 
Ynorm = spalloc(m,n,nonZeroNum); 
for i = 1:m
    Ynorm(i, :) = spfun(@(x)(x - Ymean(i)), Y(i, :));
end
```

However, this non-vectorized solution is too slow.

I've also thought of combining bsxfun and spfun, but didn't make it.

Does anyone have a vectorized solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, peasy.

A random sparse matrix.

```
A = sprand(100,100,.05);
```

Get the row means. In case there are no non-zero elements in a row, we will expect 0/0 = NaN, but then that row will never be touched by the next step.

```
rowmeans = sum(A,2)./sum(A~=0,2);
```

Extract the non-zeros.

```
[i,j.a] = find(A);
```

And restore the array, mean subtracted.

```
[n,m] = size(A);
B = sparse(i,j,a - rowmeans(i),n,m);
```

Now, test it. Don't forget that floating point arithmetic applies here, so the row means will not be exactly zero, only on the order of eps.

```
min(mean(B,2))
ans =
   (1,1)     -1.5543e-17

max(mean(B,2))
ans =
   (1,1)      1.1657e-17
```

Seems about right, and fully vectorized. To convince you that the result truly is sparse and that the zero elements have not been corrupted, here is the result of spy.

```
spy(B)
```

[image: spyplot.jpg]

Comment: [i,j.a] = find(A); should be [i,j,a] = find(A); am I right?